# AppDelegate file not working

Tags: ios, appdelegate

Hi im creating my first app with Xcode and I've imported loads of stuff into my project so I can have a tab navigation system and im getting the following errors:

[image: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BObuzzcCIAII4Ao.jpg:large]

error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AltonTowersCode", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ChessingtonCode", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_LegolandCode", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ThorpeParkCode", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Aye. How are we supposed to read that?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's AppDelegate fault, but more the header file imported and objects used.

Comment: ^^ What he said.  It looks like you imported some code.  Are all of those files in your build target?

Comment: how do I go about fixing that? Do I need to import each app delegrate

Comment: As much as I would love to say I got 20/20 eye sight, I cannot read that error. Copy and paste the whole error in your post

Comment: Ive updated it with the error im getting :(

Comment: ok... mavericks is awesome ... but ... i can't read that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing classes in your AppDelegate that you haven't added to your target.

For each of the files mentioned in the errors, do this:

Open the file and show the right pane. In one of the tabs (The Document inspector. Not the help one), there is a section called 'Target Membership' Make sure that the target that the build is failing for is checked there.

After you do those steps, a clean (<kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>) wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I had the same issue, but more cryptic errors and it was because I had the project changed in a beta version of Xcode and added a `UITextField` in the storyboard with some features only related to Xcode beta version. So when I tried to build the project in a stable version of Xcode it was throwing errors. Just needed to clean the storyboard elements and remove the ones that I added in Xcode beta version.